# Product of all numbers in a given interval $[n,m]$

Tags: recreational-mathematics, infinity, infinite-product

### Introduction

I was wondering if, you define some interval $[n,m]$ which contains all numbers between $n$ and $m$ (consider either $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb R$), what would be the product of all those numbers?

One of my instant guesses was that'll tend to infinity.

Clearly, it would be neat to assume $a\in[n,m], a\ne 0$ since the product will be $0$ otherwise.

In addition, $n,m\ge0$ since multiplying infinitely many negative numbers is undefined.

---

> **Q:** Is it correct to claim that interval type $[a\gt0,b\gt a]$ in its
>   product of all of its infinitely many real numbers, tends to $0$ no
>   matter how big $b$ is, since you can include numbers infinitely close to $0$?
>
> **A:** It seems it can either tend to $0$, $\infty$ or a finite value $x$, which is analyzed below.

Interval of type $[a\gt1,b\gt a]$, would tend to infinity in all cases since we never decrease in value no matter what number we pick to multiply next.

---

### Symmetrical expression to work multiply the numbers

Imagine taking a interval $[n,m]$, and taking the numbers for each $k$ iteration, as averages of previous numbers. Like this:

$$n,m$$
$$n,\frac{n+m}{2},m$$
$$n,\frac{3n+m}{4},\frac{n+m}{2},\frac{n+3m}{4},m$$
$$\dots$$

Which would for $k$ iterations as $k$ tends towards $\infty$, eventually contain [all numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2091761/does-this-set-contain-all-real-numbers-between-the-a-and-b) in that interval.

The product of all those numbers for $k$ iterations can be written as:

$$ \prod ^{2^k} _{x=0} \frac{(2^k - x)n+xm}{2^k} $$

If we now take an interval $[n,m]$ as $[2,3]$ for example, we have:

For $k=4$ it is: $5.11501\dots \times 10^6$

 For $k=8$ it is: $3.24661\dots \times 10^{101}$

 For $k=10$ it is: $7.56107\dots \times 10^{404}$

 And we can say it clearly tends towards $\infty$ itself.

And if we pick an interval containing numbers less than 1, we can see it can tend towards $0$;

For example: $[0.1,2],k=14$ then: $1.3926\dots \times 10^{-1062}$

But If we have a greater number, we can still tend towards infinity;

For example: $[0.1,3],k=14$ then: $8.6083\dots \times 10^{1535}$

> But then If we choose $[0.1,2.3639556]$ then for $k=14$ we will get:
>   $1.000756\dots$ 
>  Seems it tends to a bit over $1$?
>
> **Q:** Does that mean we can by choosing the right ratio, or the right
>   values in the interval, make it tend towards any value?
>
> **A:** But then If we increase the $k$, we start tending to either $\infty$ or $0$ very rapidly; for $k=16$ I had to decrease the $m$ a
>   bit to $2.3638689$ for it to be roughly $1.0076\dots$

This brings up the question;

> Can we actually make the product tend to a finite value for the case
>   where $k$ approaches $\infty$ by choosing the right ratio of $n$ and
>   $m$ in which $(n \lt 1)$ , $(m\gt 1)$?

---

### Calculating values for finite cases?

I've now tried to find the $m$ for $[0.1,m]$ so that the product of the interval ($x$) :

For $k=2$, $m\approx 3.10745$ for it to be $x\approx 1.00001$

For $k=10$, $m= 2.36569706$ for it to be $x= 1$

For $k=14$, $m\approx 2.363955478620$ for it to be $x\approx 1.00000001474698$

For $k=15$, $m\approx 2.363897553300$ for it to be $x\approx 1.00000169779107$

For $k=16$, $m\approx 2.363868593513$ for it to be $x\approx 1.00000000497575$

$$\dots$$

As you can see, for bigger $k$ we get more precision on the digits of $m$

This brings up another question;

> How would one compute $m$ with most precision for choosen $n$,
>   $(0<n<1)$ where $k$ tends to $\infty$ so that the product of all reals
>   in $[n,m]$ is a finite value $x\in \mathbb R$?

Do you have any software, any code for a computing algorithm, or a better formula than my symmetrical expression in mind? To preform the calculation where $k$ tends to $\infty$?

---

### Summing Everything up

When calculating the infinite product of all real numbers in the interval $[n,m]$, $(n\lt m)$, We have a few cases we can look at individually:

$1.$ When $n\lt0$ the result is "undefined" since we have $\infty$ many negative numbers of which we can extract $(-1)$, which can then be written as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n$ which is undefined.

$2.$ When $a\in[n,m], a=0$ The result is clearly $0$

$3.$ When $0<n<m<1$ then the result tends to $0$

$4.$ When $n>1,m>n$ the result tends to $\infty$

$5.$ When $0<n<1$ and $m>1$ The result can either tend to $0$, $\infty$ or a finite value $x$, which can be calculated by using a symmetric expression I used in my approach.

---

**Better Calculations**

> I use [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+%28%282%5E20-+t%29*0.5+%2B+t*1.6030167365305998664%29%2F%282%5E20%29,+t%3D0+to+2%5E20) while increasing $k$ but it runs up to $20$ since bigger $k$ exceed its *computational time allowed*.

When applying calculations proposed by String in his answer (using Newton-Raphson method), and feeding them to WolframAlpha, the most precision we get is (for $x=1$):

$n=\frac{1}{2}$, $m\approx 1.6030164899169670747912206652529016572070546450201637$

$n=\frac{1}{3}$, $m\approx 1.8699324270643973162008471123760292568887231725646945$

$n=\frac{1}{4}$, $m\approx 2.0245006935913233776633741232407065465057011574013821$

$n=\frac{1}{5}$, $m\approx 2.1267864647345386651244066521323021196320323179442441$
$$\dots$$

The $m$ seems to tend to $e$ as $n\to\infty$.

---

*I might get back to this if I get a chance, but I doubt it'll be soon enough.*

Comment: Note that by your iterative symmetric approach you will only get a countable subset of the uncountably many real numbers in that interval. A dense subset, nonetheless.

Comment: @String This was mainly meant to be used to get an idea of the rate the product value is tending towards depending on the $n$ number of products or $k$ iterations in a preferably symmetric way; not really the value itself really; yes to the note +1.

Comment: looks like you want the equivalent to the factorial, in that case how about the gamma function which the extensions to the real numbers of the factorial, at least for positive interval [a,b] you can do something like gamma(b)/gamma(a)

Comment: @Matta: I think I am done editing my post by now. So what do you think? I skipped details about integration and estimates thereof since you already mentioned that you do not know of that yet, but If you are interested in more details on that you could open another question or we could have an exchange elsewhere. Feel free to ask for clarifications! It was an interesting problem to work on!

Comment: @String That is a great update! May I ask what did you use on your expression to calculate the estimate of $m$? I would like to be able to compute $m$ with most precision as possible for chosen $n$ and chosen $x$. And also the other way around, for chosen finite $x$, I want to be able to compute something that will describe all possible intervals $[n,m]$ which would tend to the desired finite product $x$; possibly using your $S_k$ until a better method is found. But in fact I think that this is for another question I will probably post so I will satisfy myself with your answer on this for now.

Comment: @Matta: I calculated $m$ using a couple of iterations of the suggested Newton-Raphson method described. Just keep plugging the $x_k$ you just found into the expression for $x_{k+1}$ to get the next iteration. It converges very fast!

Comment: @String I updated my post once again to point out what is still a part of the question in the very last section of the post; thus were you plugging in those Newton-Raphson equations into WolframAlpha to get the digits? I need a explained method of how to compute those values most easily, quickly and with most precision as possible; which you can include in your answer to complete it.

Comment: @Matta: My analysis shows that for each given $0<n<1$ there is exactly one value of $1<m<\operatorname e$ such that the products tend to a finite value. That finite value will then be $x=\sqrt{m\cdot n}$. In fact it turns out that we always have $0<x<1$. I tested your value $m=1.6030167365305998664$ using Maple and high precision and found that $T_{20}\approx 0.999999999999929147$ whereas $T_{50}\approx 1.31204\times 10^{51589023}$. So it explodes after a while.

Comment: @Matta: Whereas using $n=0.5$ and $m=1.603016489916967074791$ which were the digits only five steps of the Newton-Raphson method gave me, I get $T_{50}\approx0.8952698$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Definition of the interval

One possible definition given a strictly positive interval $[n,m]\subseteq\mathbb R^+$ could be:
$$
\prod_{x\in [n,m]}x:=\exp\left(\int_n^m\ln(x)\ dx\right)
=\frac{m^m\cdot n^{-n}} {\operatorname e^{m-n}}
$$
for an interval $[n,m]$ containing uncountably many elements. The countable and finite versions could then read
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k:=\exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ln(x_k)\right)
\quad\text{and}\quad
\prod_{k=1}^n x_k:=\exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(x_k)\right)=x_1\cdot x_2\cdot ...\cdot x_n
$$

---

We could even extend this definition to
$$
\prod_{x\in [n,m]}f(x):=\exp\left(\int_n^m\ln(f(x))\ dx\right)
$$
One nice property is that with this defition we have
$$
\prod_{x\in[n,m]} x^a=\left(\prod_{x\in[n,m]} x\right)^a
$$
so it appears to follow some nice rules of powers of conventional finite products.

---

To define it without direct use of integration, my definition should be equivalent to the defining:
$$
S_k:=\prod_{x=0}^{2^k}\left(\frac{(2^k-x)n+xm}{2^k}\right)^{(m-n)/2^k}
$$
and recognize the product $\prod_{x\in [n,m]}x$ as the limit of those $S_k$'s as $k$ tends to infinity. So it is like multiplying together $2^k+1$ evenly spread out factors over the interval $[n,m]$, but adjusting the exponent of each factor to match the distance between the factors, namely $(m-n)/2^k$. These exponents tend to zero as the number of factors tends to infinity. It can then be shown that $S_k\to m^m\cdot n^{-n}/\operatorname e^{m-n}$.

---

So how does this relate to your suggested symmetrical expression? Well, you are considering the sequence of the form:
$$
T_k:=(S_k)^{2^k/(m-n)}=\prod_{x=0}^{2^k}\frac{(2^k-x)n+xm}{2^k}
$$
Now clearly, if $S_k\to a>1$ we will have $T_k\to\infty$ whereas for $S_k\to a\in[0,1)$ we must have $T_k\to0$. So the difficult cases are $S_k\to 1$ or $S_k\to a<0$. The latter I doubt we can make any sense of.

### Resolving when $S_k$ tends to $1$

If $S_k$ tends to $1$ for some $n\in(0,1)$ and an appropriate matching $m>1$ we then know that
$$
\int_n^m\ln(x)\ dx=\lim_{k\to\infty}\ln(S_k)=\ln(1)=0
$$
Considering the graph of $\ln(x)$ it can be shown that
$$
\left[\ln m -q_k\cdot(\ln m -\ln n)\right]\cdot\Delta x\leq\ln(S_k)\leq\left[\ln n +(1-q_k)\cdot(\ln m -\ln n)\right]\cdot\Delta x
$$
where $0.5\leq q_k\leq 1$ is a sequence tending to $0.5$, and $\Delta x$ is short hand for the distance $(m-n)/2^k$. Since $T_k$ is equal to $S_k$ except for raising to the reciprocal of $\Delta x$ we get $\ln(T_k)=\ln(S_k)/\Delta x$ and therefore
$$
\left[\ln m-q_k\cdot(\ln m -\ln n)\right]\leq\ln(T_k)\leq\left[\ln n +(1-q_k)\cdot(\ln m -\ln n)\right]
$$
As $k$ tends to infinity both bounds tend to $(\ln m+\ln n )/2$ showing us that
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} T_k=\exp\left(\frac{\ln m+\ln n}2\right)=\sqrt{n\cdot m}
$$

Now we should able to do the following:

### Resolving the computation method

Given $n\in(0,1)$ one can solve
$$
\int_n^m\ln(x)\ dx=m(\ln m-1)-n(\ln n-1)=0
$$
for $m>1$ in order to find the corresponding $m$ so that $T_k$ converges. One way to do this is to use the [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) on the function
$$
f(x)=x(\ln x-1)-n(\ln n-1)
$$
with initial guess $x_0=2$. Then $m=\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k$ where the $x_k$'s are defined recursively as
$$
x_{k+1}:=x_k-\frac{x_k(\ln x_k-1)-n(\ln n-1)}{\ln x_k}
$$
It turns out that in fact $1<m<\operatorname e\approx 2.7182818$. For $n=0.5$ it takes only a few iterations before one has
$$
m\approx x_5=1.603016489916967074791...
$$
and it can be verified that the digits listed above do not change for future iterations so we already have $m$ to a very high precision. So we have
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\prod ^{2^k} _{x=0} \frac{(2^k - x)0.5+x\cdot 1.603016489916967074791...}{2^k}\\=\sqrt{0.5\cdot 1.603016489916967074791...}\approx 0.8952699285458456285
$$
But this is a very unstable result anyway! My earlier computations showed that if $m$ is either the slightest bit larger than the actual solution to $f(x)=0$ the product tends to infinity, or if it is the slightest bit less then it tends to zero.

### Some general remarks to conclude

The infinite symmetrical product you defined is very unstable in more than one respect. If we change the definition even slightly we may get an entirely different result:
$$
\prod ^{2^k} _{x=1} \frac{(2^k - x)n+xm}{2^k}
$$
removes the first factor $n$ whereas
$$
\prod ^{2^k-1} _{x=0} \frac{(2^k - x)n+xm}{2^k}
$$
removes the last factor $m$. Whereas these would both lead to the same values of $S_k$ removing only a negligible contribution at that level, they affect the value of $T_k$ by a non-negligible factor. Also if we distributed the factors in the interval $[n,m]$ slightly different the product $T_k$ could change a lot whereas $S_k$ would not. So overall $S_k$ is a much more stable value. And $S_k$ tends to represent an actually uncountable product, whereas $T_k$ tends to something I would characterize as product of a countable subset of the factors in question. This might be another reason it is so unstable - there are infinitely many other ways we could have defined $T_k$ that would yield totally different results whereas all definitions of $S_k$ by partitioning $[n,m]$ into subintervals that decrease toward zero width as $k$ tends to infinity would all point to the same limit value of $S_k$. This in a sense addresses your **question 1** as an infinite product of the kind you are suggesting would or would not tend to zero depending on the distribution you use to select factors from $[n,m]$.

Comment: I like how you attached some values to those different kinds of the interval by those definitions +1. Integration is still unknown to me since by our school program we won't be mentioning it until the very end of our next school year so I can't really give a mathematical opinion on your idea.

Comment: @Matta: I have added a last part where I try to define it without using integration. I hope it at least provides some idea of what the idea behind my approach is.

Comment: @Matta: As you can see, it is closely related to the idea you had about choosing evenly spread out factors in the interval. The main difference is that the "weight" of each factor in the product is diminished as the number of factors grow in my version. This is why my definition provides finite values as a result.

Comment: Thanks for the update, now its easy to see the beauty behind your approach!

Comment: I've updated my post by pointing out the $5$ questions that need an answer, and your answer would be pointing out to the question $(5)$? And I've updated my symmetrical expression, made it simple, so I can easily evaluate the values when selecting variables, and looks like my values aren't finite for $k$ approaching $\infty$ where yours are ?(Look at my [2,3] example and yours) What do you think?

Comment: @Matta: That is a nice update, indeed! Perhaps I can get around to addressing some of the other questions as well. That may make me want to update my current answer to (5) to make it more brief. I will re-consider and return.

Comment: I've done some calculations, and made a update to the post; basically I'm now most interested in finding a way to calculate $m$ with most precision as possible so that for $n : (0<n<1)$ the infinite product is a finite value.

Comment: Quote: *One nice property is that with this defition we have*
$$
\prod_{x\in[n,m]} x^a=\left(\prod_{x\in[n,m]} x\right)^a
$$ Why is that so? I see no definition of products such as $$
\prod_{x\in[n,m]} f(x)$$ except if $f$ is the identity, but you are referring to a definition for $f(x)=x^\alpha$...

Comment: @Did: Sorry, you are right! That is because I removed that other definition for brevity and forgot that now it is no longer there. I should add it back again!

Comment: @Did: It should be fixed now. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @String Just one more thing I want to understand, does now in theory for example, the example $[2,3]$ tend to $\infty$ as my "countable" expression says, the $T_k$ as you defined it, or does it $\approx 2.4853\dots$ as your "uncountable" $S_k$ gives for $k=10$ ? This looks to me like somewhat of a contradiction in these supposed infinite cases of $x$ even tho the both $S_k$ and $T_k$ seem to agree on the supposed finite cases of $x$.

Comment: @Matta: They are always two different aspects of the same partitions of $[n,m]$ that become finer and finer as $k$ increases. Only $S_k$ is weighted according to intervals of real numbers whereas $T_k$ does no weighting of the factors. I will add a little section at the end concluding how $\lim_{k\to\infty}S_k$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty}T_k$ are related for the different cases.

Comment: @String I just noticed that your definition of $S_k$ might be wrong for this case. You noted that "exponent approaches zero as $k$ tends to infinity", doesn't that mean that the numbers in the product tend to $1$ then? (number $a^b$ where $b$ tends to $0$, tends to $1$) So that might be the reason why it gives always finite values, since it in reality takes numbers less than $n$ if $n$ is $\gt1$ and thus actually is not respecting the limitation of the interval $[n,m]$ in cases when $n\gt1$ or $m\lt1$?

Comment: @Matta: I am not sure what your objection is. Which case do you think $\lim_{k\to\infty}S_k$ is incorrect for? You are right that $S_k$ is very different from simply multiplying lots of numbers in the interval $[n,m]$ together. It uses those numbers, but as the number of factors increases the effect of each factor is diminished. So it does respect the limitation of the interval which is also why it tends to $m^m\cdot n^{-n}/\operatorname e^{m-n}$ which indeed reflects $n$ and $m$. It is just very different to the non-weighted $T_k$ that most of the time tends to zero or infinity!

Comment: @Matta: My approach comes closer to the midpoint of $[n,m]$ being raised to the $(m-n)$-th power and so it represents the value of a product related to all number in the interval, only each number in the interval carries a weight tending to zero as $k$ increases. This is like continuous probability measures: The uniform probability of getting any given number in the interval $[n,m]$ is in fact zero, but the probability of getting a number in the subinterval $[a,b]$ is $(b-a)/(m-n)$

Comment: @String Maybe I fail to understand your expression because I simply haven't been introduced to limits and integrals by my school program yet. But still that doesn't change the fact that; How come your $S_k$ is allowed to give finite values in these infinite cases is my biggest question, since the expression to calculate the product of all real numbers between $2$ real numbers $\gt1$ should be infinite since you are by each factor always increasing in value?

Comment: @Matta: Yes, and your $T_k=S_k^{2^k/(m-n)}$ does in fact tend to infinity for $n,m>1$. But since $S_k=T_k^{(m-n)/2^k}$ the exponent stops it before infinity and this represents giving the factors of each subinterval a weight that corresponds to its width. In your product each factor has exponent $1$ since $a^1=a$ whereas in my product the weight is diminished according to the size of the subinterval the factor represents.

Comment: @String I forgot you were refereeing to the subquestion $4$ and that the $S_k$ is then actually a way to assign values to otherwise infinite values, am I right? I'm sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: @Matta: You are right, that's it! No problem! Perhaps I can add a little detail that somehow gives you a better idea of what it is. A small preview of integration without going into too much detail ... I will think about it.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as a product of uncountably many numbers (where not most of them are $=1$ or some are $=0$). Compare to sums: Even with countably many summnds, we do not speak of *sums*, but of *series* (even though we suggestively use the same symbol $\sum$ for both). Those have very different properties from sums: A sum of rationals is always defined, is always a rational, and does not depend on the order of summation. On the other hand, a series of rationals may fail to converge, or converge to an irrational number, or converge to different values if we change the order of the terms. So to repeat: Even a "sum" of *countably* many numbers is not really a sum. A "sum" of *uncountably* many (non-zero) summands  is even more horrible: For any such best there must exist some $\epsilon>0$ such that uncountably many terms are $>\epsilon$, or uncountzably many terms are $<-\epsilon$; already their contribution is (positive or negative) infinite. It is not an easy task, especially for an arbitrary index set, to assign any meaning to this. The same argument holds for products (if not with some extra considerations).

That being said, you gave a specific definition of an expression $$P(a,b)=\lim_{n\to\infty}P(a,b;2^n),$$
where
$$P(a,b;N)=\prod_{j=0}^N\frac{(N-j)a+jb}{N}, $$ which we shall investigate (and better forget that we want to call this "product of all numbers in $[a,b]$).
Consider first the case $0<a<b$.
$$\frac1N\ln P(a,b;N) = \sum_{j=0}^N\frac1N\ln \frac{(N-j)a+jb}{N},$$
which looks a lot like a [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum). Indeed, as $\ln$ is strictly increasing, we see that
$$ \frac1N\ln P(a,b;N)=\int_a^b\ln x\,\mathrm dx+R_n$$
where $\frac 1N\ln a<R_n<\frac 1N\ln b$. As $x(\ln x-1)$ is an anti-derivative fo the logarithm, we arrive at
$$ P(a,b;N) = \bigl(e^{b(\ln b-1)-a(\ln a-1)}\bigr)^N\cdot c_N$$
with $a<c_N<b$. The limit as $N\to\infty$ can only exist if $$b(\ln b-1)=a(\ln a-1).$$
Such pairs $(a,b)$ are rare: The function $x\mapsto x(\ln x-1)$ decreases from $1$ to $0$ on $(0,1]$, and then increases, reaching $1$ at $x=e$. Hence the only suitable pairs $(a,b)$ are with $0<a<1$ and one suitable $1<b<e$.
By investigating $c_N$ closer (comparing with the [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule)), one arrives at
$P(a,b)=\sqrt ab$ for such $a,b$.

Interestingly, if $P(a,b)$ exists, we also have $P(-b,-a)=-P(a,b)$. This is because the specific definition of $P(a,b)$ uses only $P(a,b; 2^n)$ and for $n>0$ we have $P(a,b,2^n)=P(-b,-a,2^n)$. *(Though for me this fun result is more a hint that the definition of $P$ is not perfect)*

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications!

Comment: This is a very nice answer! It puts more succintly some of my concerns about such an uncountable product having any natural interpretation in the first place. This answer sees the problems with this in a much clearer light than I ever did, indeed :o)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the Riemann integral $$\int_a^bx\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\cdot\Delta x_k$$ where the limit is taken in such a way so that the maximum $\Delta x_i$ approaches $0$. You are adding up all real numbers between $a$ and $b$, but weighted by the infinitesimally small $dx$. You could try to so the same with a product. Try to multiply all numbers together, "weighted" appropriately. With a Riemann sum, you multiply each $x_i$ by $\Delta x_i$, where the sum of the $\Delta x_i$ accounts for the full difference from $a$ to $b$. I think the analogous thing would be to raise each $x_i$ by a power $Rx_i$ where the product of the $Rx_i$ accounts for the full ratio from $a$ to $b$. [$R$ stands for ratio; it would be like the ratio of two adjacent $x_i$.]

In the same way that $\int$ is a fancy "S" for sum, you could define $$\DeclareMathOperator*{\pint}{\mathcal{P}}\pint_a^b x^{Rx}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^nx_k^{Rx_k}$$

But this is no good. In the limit, each $Rx_i$ would approach $1$, so you would be multiplying numbers that are too large together. You want the $Rx_i$ to approach $0$ so the product is of numbers close to $1$. You could consider using $\Delta x_i$ in the exponents, but unlike $Rx_i$, $\Delta x_i$ is not unitless. So it feels out of place in an exponent. I can't think of a theoretical justification, but the following seems worth exploring:

$$\DeclareMathOperator*{\pint}{\mathcal{P}}\pint_a^b x^{Rx}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^nx_k^{\ln(Rx_k)}$$ where the limit is taken in such a way so that the $Rx_i$ approach $1$. For example, with $a=1$, $b=2$, $x_k=2^{k/n}$, $Rx_k=2^{1/n}$:

$$\begin{align}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\pint}{\mathcal{P}}\pint_1^2 x^{Rx}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n\left(2^{k/n}\right)^{\ln(2^{1/n})}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n2^{k\ln(2)/n^2}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{\sum_{k=1}^nk\ln(2)/n^2}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{\ln(2)\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}}\\
&=2^{\ln(2)/2}\\
&\approx1.2715\ldots
\end{align}$$

Note: this gives the same result if $\ln(Rx_i)$ is replaced by $Rx_i-1$.

Comment: It looks like variants on this have been around for a while: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral).

Comment: Interesting post and interesting link!