# What are the odds of picking a number in a given set for it to be also contained in its subset?

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, infinity

> If we define a set $[A,B]$ and a set $[a,b]$ which is contained inside
>   the first set, what are the odds when picking a number from set
>   $[A,B]$ that it is also contained inside the set $[a,b]$  if all
>   numbers are equally likely to be picked?

If elements in our sets are $\in\mathbb N$, then we can simply divide the number of all elements we can pick from and the number of elements in our target set, making our odds:

$$p({\mathbb N})= \frac{b-a+1}{B-A+1}$$

For $\in\mathbb Z$, we simply watch out for the negatives:

$$p({\mathbb Z})= \frac{|b-a|+1}{|B-A|+1}$$

---

But what about when our sets are rational,  $\in\mathbb Q$?

 If we define our sets like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2091777/318073), we have:

$$p({\mathbb Q})=\frac{|b-a|+1+(|b-a|)\times n}{|B-A|+1+(|B-A|)\times n}, n\to\infty$$

If we take the limit as $n$ approaches $\infty$, we finally get:

$$p({\mathbb Q})=\frac{|b-a|}{|B-A|}$$

Is this a valid solution?

---

> Also, I'm wondering how could one define these sets for $\in\mathbb R$ and
>   calculate $p(\mathbb R)$? 
>   
>  What about $p(\mathbb C)$?

Comment: I don't understand the notation.  Your set $(A,B)$ has two elements?  Or do you mean something like $x\in \mathbb R$ such that $A≤x≤B$?

Comment: @lulu The second thing, edited the question replacing () with [].

Comment: But why not spell out exactly what you mean?  I just guessed that you meant a subset of the reals....that's the sort of thing that should be stated.

Comment: To your question:  I think you are asking about measure theory.  If your sets have a nice geometry to them you can just take the ratio of the areas.  If not, well you need something like a measure.  There are some pretty bad sets out there...it's hard to come up with a notion that makes sense in all cases.

Comment: @lulu Ah yes this was almost 4 years ago when I wasn't familiar with measure theory (or any formal probability). If you'd wanted to turn your comment into an answer, I'd accept that.